# How can I make the commit wait until the if statement has ran?

Tags: mysql, node.js, async-await

The function makes a transaction using mysql2 and the promise wrapper. 
For each task, there can be multiple links, formatted in JSON.

For each link, I need to insert into the DB, after the task has been inserted. However, if the JSON is wrong (see "no" not "name" below), an error needs to be thrown and the commit should never happen.

```
{
    "title": "Test new from POSTMAN many link",
    "header": "POSTMAN test many links",
    "category": "POSTMAN test many links",
    "notes": "Task created from POSTMAN many link",
    "links": [{"name": "Lenovo", "link": "https://www.lenovo.com"}, {"no": "Microsoft", "link": "https://www.microsoft.com"}],
    "level": 2 
}
```

I have tried the nested try/catch block but this does not run before the commit below it

```js
await conn.beginTransaction();
        const [task] = await conn.query("INSERT INTO tasks SET ? ", [taskObj]);
        if (req.body.links.length > 0) {
            req.body.links.map(async e => {
                try {
                    const link = {
                        task_id: task.insertId,
                        name: e.name,
                        link: e.link
                    };
                    await conn.query("INSERT INTO links SET ? ", [link]);
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    conn.rollback();
                    conn.release();
                }
            });
        }

        // this runs before my if statement above
        console.log("about to commit");
        await conn.commit();
        conn.release();
        return res.send({ data: taskObj, message: "Task created" });
    } catch (e) {
        conn.rollback();
        conn.release();
        console.log(e);
        return res.send({ message: "error" });
    }
```

I want the error to ensure the commit doesn't happen if either the task insert fails or a link insert fails.

Comment: Just a suggestion, look for https://knexjs.org/ it has simple API, and transactions could be run like this `await dbConnection(async transaction => {... do your async task inside transaction. Throw error if something didn't work out and transaction would be rolled back})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See example:

```
(async () => {
  try {
    await conn.beginTransaction();
    const [task] = await conn.query("INSERT INTO tasks SET ? ", [taskObj]);
    if (req.body.links.length > 0) {
      const promises = req.body.links.map(async e => {
        const link = {
          task_id: task.insertId,
          name: e.name,
          link: e.link
        };
        await conn.query("INSERT INTO links SET ? ", [link]);
      });
      await Promise.all(promises);
    }

    // this runs before my if statement above
    console.log("about to commit");
    await conn.commit();
    conn.release();
    return res.send({ data: taskObj, message: "Task created" });
  } catch (e) {
    await conn.rollback();
    await conn.release();
    console.log(e);
    return res.send({ message: "error" });
  }
})();
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. 

To clarify my understanding, is promises a variable storing a reference to all the conn.query and then executing them?

Comment: The variable `promises` stores Promise objects created using the `map` function. The Promise.all() method returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises passed as an iterable have resolved or when the iterable contains no promises. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all